# Why when passing a variable between 2 functions, is the variable None when it isn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

I'm making a basic editing software.

A simplified version of parts of the code are below (and they still produce the same result as with the actual program):

File named `mod.py`:

```py
from mod2 import toptext

cmdtext = "Edit video: tt=test,"

presentCommands = ['tt=']

def initCommands(presentCommands, cmdtext):
    vidfilter = []
    if 'tt=' in presentCommands and 'bt=' not in presentCommands:
        vidfilter = toptext(cmdtext, vidfilter)
        print("Top text vidfilter is", vidfilter)
    else:
        print('no')

initCommands(presentCommands, cmdtext)
```

File named `mod2.py`:

```py
import re

def toptext(cmdtext, vidfilter):
    vidfilter = vidfilter
    texts = (re.findall(r'tt=(.*?),', cmdtext))
    text = texts[0]
    print(text)
    vidfilter = vidfilter.append("subtitles=/example/file/path/toptext.srt:force_style='Fontname=Impact,Fontsize=30,Alignment=6'")
    print("The vidfilter is:", vidfilter)
    return vidfilter
```

The output of running `mod.py` is this:

```
test
The vidfilter is: None
Top text vidfilter is None
```

As you can see, vidfilter is printed as `None`, when I want it to be `["subtitles=/example/file/path/toptext.srt:force_style='Fontname=Impact,Fontsize=30,Alignment=6'"]` instead. Is `append()` not working or something?

Can anyone please help me fix this and let me know why it's happening? Please note I'd like to keep `mod.py` and `mod2.py` as separate files.

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` works in place (and thus return `None`). You assign it back to `vidfilter` on this line:

```
vidfilter = vidfilter.append("subtitles=/example/file/path/toptext.srt:force_style='Fontname=Impact,Fontsize=30,Alignment=6'")
```

Also note that I am not sure what you think this like is doing:

```
vidfilter = vidfilter
```

Comment: oh sorry - didnt mean to have the vidfilter = vidfilter there! i'll try your solution now